# In a pipe, how can a program downstream get the exit code of a program upstream after end-of-input?

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, exit-code

I wrote a program which waits for data on standard input, writes it to a 
temporary location and moves it to a user-specified location upon end-of-input.

By this, I want to enable pipelines like this

```
# Does not work; truncates myfile
cat myfile | some_filter > myfile 
# shall enable pseudo-inplace modification
cat myfile | some_filter | my_program myfile
```

But my program currently writes to the file regardless whether the pipe upstream was successful. I want to avoid data loss if upstream encountered an error and therefore abort the program if one of the programs upstream the pipe threw an error.

As of now, I wrote the program in bash but am not confined to it.

How can I check this within my program?

**EDIT:** To be more specific: I want to spare my user to deal with creating temporary files, check the success of intermediate programs and similar as much as possible. I want the user to be able to invoke some program (e.g. to add a column to a text file, sort, filter, whatever) on some file and write the result back to that same file, but only if the intermediate progamms returned success.

Comment: You can try using mktemp to make a temp file, write to the temp file, check if the process finished successfully, then write from the temp file to your file, delete temp file.

Comment: To explain what @dood said: `tmpfile=$(mktemp); process1 | process2 > $tmpfile && mv $tmpfile myfile`

Comment: Also, `cat myfile | some_filter` is [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). Use `some_filter < myfile` instead.

Comment: @dood Yes, that's essentially what I wrote into my program. However, I want to mask this from the user, thats why I asked whether it is possible to check for error codes of upstream program _from within_ downstream programs.

Comment: @anishsane You are absolutely right, I wrote this only for better visualization of the pipeline structure.

Answer (score 1):

A redirection, eg `> file` is handled by the shell, which opens the file for writing before invoking the command. A workaround for this is - as suggested by @dood in the comments, using a temporary file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
a file | b | c > "$tmp"; && mv "$tmp" file
```

Now the file created by `mktemp` is used for the redirection. And then after the file is moved to `file`.

This will however only check the last command in the pipe and move if that was successful.

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) there is a variable named `PIPESTATUS` that contains all exit statuses for the pipe, eg:

```
% ls | cat | cat
% echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 0 0
```

And a failure:

```
% ls | cat | false
% echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 141 1
```

You can use this to check if all commands in the pipe successfully exited:

```
% ls | cat | cat
% [[ "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" =~ ^0( 0)*$ ]] && echo "good"
good
```

And with your example:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
some_filter < myfile > "$tmp"
[[ "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" =~ ^0( 0)*$ ]] && mv "$tmp" "myfile"
```

The regex `^0( 0)*$` matches `0`, `0 0`, `0 0 0`, ... So basically matches if all commands in the pipe exited successfully.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to encapsulate into a program: My user sholdn't have to bother creating a temporary file, reading the pipe status and ensuring the temporary file is deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of running commands in a pipeline is that they execute concurrently.  When you run `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`, `cmd3` very likely starts executing before `cmd1` is finished.  So, unless you can invoke a Star Trek style temporal anomaly, there is no way to determine the exit status of cmd1 before cmd3 starts.  If you need to wait until cmd1 finishes before you begin cmd3, you cannot put them in the same pipeline.  Well, that's not quite true, you can do hacks like;

`mkfifo /tmp/foo; { cmd1; echo > /tmp/foo; } | cmd2 | { cat /tmp/foo; cmd3; }`

but why would you want to?   (Note that even in this case, the commands in the final part of the pipeline do execute before cmd1 finishes, but the `cat` blocks so that the execution of `cmd3` is delayed.)

Also note that no matter what you try, there is a potential deadlock.  If the pipes get full, cmd1 and cmd2 will block indefinitely on a write and cmd3 will never start.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. But is it possible to have the following time course: cmd1, cmd2 and cmd3 all start, cmd3 reads all the output from cmd1|cmd2, until end-of-transmission. This means cmd2 has closed its output, therefore cmd3 should be able to get the exit status of cmd2 at that point?

Comment: Sure: `cmd1 | cmd2 > /tmp/foo && cmd3 < /tmp/foo`  Put `/tmp` on a ram disk if you want to be sure you never hit a disk. You can try using named pipes and the like, but there will always be a potential deadlock, and regular files are the best way to avoid those issues.